# Who is God of Oldness? What are the details about him?

Tags: vedas, gods, age

Jara is called the god of oldness. Who is he? Where does he live? Any story about him?
Anyone who has defeated him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jara, in fact, is a goddess- a female. Information about her is hard to come by, so I'll present it anectdotally, in bullets.

- She is  the *Goddess of Old Age, *and* The Daughter of Death.*
- From her name comes *j=Jaramarana*, an Indo-Buddhist name for the belief that the moment one is born, their life is a march towards death. (That living and dying are one and the same.)
- She is found only in the Bhagavad Gita ([List of References](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/w/jara))

There's one examination, which you can find [here](https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Jara_means), which came to the conclusion that

> Jara, the effect of old age, does not harass a devotee. This is because a devotee follows the instructions and the determination of Narada Muni

Unfortunately, that's rather difficult to parse through, but what I take it to mean is that *one shouldn't fear old age, nor death, for the enlightened (devotees), understand that, per Narada Muni's declarations, it is no punishment.*

---

I found *one* other reference to Jara, in the book *[Sacred Places of The Goddess](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sacred_Places_of_Goddess/f5tREAAAQBAJ?gbpv=1&bsq=nirriti).* It is included in an entry for the goddess Nirriti, who represents death and decay:

> **Nirriti** (Indian): One of the earliest Hindu deities, she may have been associated with the **pre-Aryan Jara who has been described as youthful and monstress**, a discrepancy which may be related to the reconciliation between pre-Aryan and Vedic traditions. Nirrti later becomes associated with Kali, Yami, and Earth itself.

Comment: I think this Jara was who brought Jarasandha to life after his birth.

Comment: Dhumavati is a Mahavidya which I believe also signifies old age.